# Could someone explain this notation and explain what this question is asking?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Show $\{0,1\}^V\approx\wp(V)$.

The $≈$ denotes that there is a bijection between $\{0,1\}^V$ and the powerset of $V$. However, I can't understand what $\{0,1\}^V$ is if $V$ is a set?

Comment: $A^B$ is the collection of mappings from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown that explains a lot

Comment: Given an element of $f\in\{0,1\}^V$ map it to the set $\{x\in V:\ f(x)=1\}\subset V$.